# How to call function on button click OR dropdown change jquery

Tags: jquery, event-handling

right now, I have an event handler that looks like this

```
   $('#nextMonth, #prevMonth').click(function() {
      // execute code
   });
```

but trying to make it look something more like this, but not sure how to write it in a way that works

```
   $('#nextMonth, #prevMonth').click || $('.yearSelect).change(function() {
      // execute code
   });
```

so basically, if `#nextMonth` / `#prevMonth` is clicked, run the function, or if `$('.yearSelect')` is changed (a dropdown menu), then execute the code in the function. What would be the correct way to write this?

Answer (score 2):

To execute common code from different event handlers, you can move the common code in javascript / jquery function and call it from event handlers

```
$('#nextMonth, #prevMonth').click(function() {
  commonExecution();
});

$('.yearSelect').change(function() {
  commonExecution();
});

function commonExecution() { 
  // execute code
}
```

Comment: @Kaddath OP need change event on different element and click event on different element

Comment: I need to drink another coffee it seems :D